# How do Enable/Disable linkbutton in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a link button in the page like:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="edit" runat="server" OnClick="edit_Click" Enabled="False">ویرایش</asp:LinkButton>
```

I want Enable/Disable this in javascript.

I use this code but set visible

```
var objedit = document.getElementById('<%= edit.ClientID.ToString() %>');
objedit.style.display = "none";
```

I use this code but not enable

```
if (count == 1) {
    objedit.disabled = false;
} else {
    objedit.disabled = true;
}
```

I can click but link button is disabled.

[image]

Comment: what you want ? disable or hidden the element ?

Comment: display the element . I want show 'Edit Item' like 'New Item'

Comment: hey pesar , farsi begoo , motavajeh nashodam manzooret chie?

Comment: man ye linkbutton daram ke mikham enable/disable konam az hame in coda ham estefade kardam vali hamintor ke toie ax mibinin be sorat disable neshon mide , albate mitonam click konam vali karbar be sorat gheir faal mibine :)

Comment: Check out my [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/hzaR6/2/).

Comment: @ar.gorgin, what is not working? It works on Google Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I use this code and run in IE but don't enable linkbutton.

Answer (score 1):

So, is this what you want?
[***`http://jsfiddle.net/hzaR6/`***](http://jsfiddle.net/hzaR6/)
[***`http://jsfiddle.net/hzaR6/2/`***](http://jsfiddle.net/hzaR6/2/) -- UPDATED, tested in Chrome and Firefox

### The UPDATED way

You can use a `class` name to define disabled element, for which you can have more control on their styles ... etc.

```
$("#link").toggleClass("disabled"); //This will simply toggle the class
```

and for the css

```css
#link.disabled{
    z-index:-1;            /*Make it not clickable*/
    position:relative;
    opacity: .5;           /*Lighter*/
}​
```

You can do whatever you want here.

### The good old `form` element way

```
$("#edit").attr("disabled", false);
 -or-
document.getElementBy("edit").disabled = false;
```

This will disable any form element. If you want to enable them, just change `false` to `true`.

---

```
var a = document.getElementBy("edit").disabled;
```

`a` will be `true` if the element is disabled. Otherwise it will be `false`.

Comment: I had the same thought, but this solution doesn't work on asp.net link buttons (they are just hyperlinks with javascript attached to their onclick handlers)  see here: http://jsfiddle.net/hzaR6/1/.

Comment: @Derek - you're right.  If the OP wants to disable a linkbutton via javascript, he either needs to change the onclick event or the linkbutton itself, or use an asp:button instead (in which case, your solution would work).

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1148848.aspx/1) should give you everything you need.  You can't really "disable" a linkbutton because its just a link with some javascript attached.  Basically, you need to [reassign the click handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376444/how-to-disable-a-href-link-in-javascript) to something that returns void or false.

You can refer to the ID of the link with the following script:

```
<script runat="server">
   var a = document.getElementById('<%= edit.ClientID.ToString() %>')
</script>
```

Comment: @argorgin:  Did you look at the links I posted?  You need to reassign the onclick event handler of the linkbutton:     a.onclick = function(){};

Comment: I set Attribute for linkbutton (onclick).

Answer (score 1):

To disable element:

```
document.getElementById('<%# edit.ClientID %>').disabled = 'disabled';
//.ToString() is not necessary; ClientID is a string.
```

To re-enable:

```
document.getElementById('<%# edit.ClientID %>').disabled = '';
```

Of course, it can be done after document (DOM) is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var objedit = document.getElementById("edit"); //not editid (editid is a variable)
objedit.disabled = true; //if I'm not mistaken its true/false or disabled
```

Comment: I use this code but linkbutton is disable . I mean, the buttons on the form is displayed.

Comment: Ok , i use this code . i can click on button but linkbutton is displayed.

Comment: wait man, i don't seemed to understand what you wanted to do, can you please clarify your question?

Comment: Plz show picture. I use this code(objedit.disabled = false;). but Edit Item is displayed .it should display like 'New Item'

Comment: you don't disabled it you remove it  "(objedit.disabled == false) ? NewItem.style.display = none : NewItem.style.display = block; "where your NewItem is the Id of your New Item." .. I really don't get what are you trying to do

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("lnk").style.display = "none";
```