# Disable report button link does NOT want to disable - html5

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html

The button is not disabled when I click on it, here with my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetNewsCommentReportFlag(newsCommentId) {
        $("#news-comment" + newsCommentId).text("This comment has been removed");
        $("#post-button" + newsCommentId).attr("onclick", "this.disabled=true;");
        var jqxhr = $.getJSON("<%= 
                Url.Action(
                    "SetNewsCommentReportFlag", 
                    "Home", 
                    new { area = "News" }
                ) 
            %>?newsCommentId=" + newsCommentId, function (data) { });
    }
</script>


<div class="news-comment" id="news-comment<%: Model.NewsCommentId %>">
    <% if (Model.Reported)
    {
        Model.NewsComment = "This comment has been removed";    
    } else  %>
    <%: Model.NewsComment %>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="actions-right">    
    <a href="javascript:SetNewsCommentReportFlag(<%: Model.NewsCommentId %>);" 
        class="button" id="post_button<%: Model.NewsCommentId %>"
    ><%: Html.Resource(Resources.Global.Button.Report) %></a>                
</div>
```

like this?:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetNewsCommentReportFlag(newsCommentId) {
        $("#news-comment" + newsCommentId).text("This comment has been removed");
        $("#post-button" + newsCommentId).attr("onclick", "this.disabled=true;");
            var jqxhr = $.getJSON(
                "/News/Home/SetNewsCommentReportFlag?newsCommentId=" 
                + newsCommentId, function (data) { }
            );
    }
</script>

<div class="news-post-list-item">
    <div class="news-post-user-info-wrapper">
        <div class="avatar">
            <img src="/ThemeFiles/Base/images/User/user-avatar.png" 
                width="52" height="52" alt="Avatar" />   
        </div>
        <div class="who-and-when-box">
            25/02/2013 13:20:56
            <br />
            <br />
            Cecilia Torres Castro 
        </div>
        <div class="news-comment" id="news-comment3">
            sdfsdf
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="actions-right">    
            <a href="javascript:SetNewsCommentReportFlag(3);" 
                class="button" id="post_button3">Report</a>                
        </div>
    </div>     
    <div class="clear"></div> 
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong please?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using an actual button, you're using an anchor tag:

```
<a href="javascript:SetNewsCommentReportFlag(3);" class="button" id="post_button3">Report</a>
```

These can't be disabled using `disabled=true`, that only works on actual buttons.

Because you are using an anchor tag instead of a real button, you have to do it slightly differently.

See:

[jQuery disable a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970388/jquery-disable-a-link)

or

[How do I disable a href link in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376444/how-to-disable-a-href-link-in-javascript)

You will also have to give the disabled 'button' a new css class to make it look visually disabled too.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding an `onclick` event to disable it, but after that line **you are already disabling it**.

Because you have already disabled the element, no events will fire on it. Even if they did, they'd produce the same result in the element being disabled. I think you need to get rid of this line:

```
$("#post-button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Also, you have syntax issues in this line:

```
post_button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.disabled=true;");
```

Change it to:

```
$("#post_button").attr("onclick", "this.disabled=true;");
```

Comment: i took that out but also get an error on the add line saying unable to get value of the property "add"?

Comment: Change that line to be ` $("#post_button").attr("onclick", "this.disabled=true;");`

Comment: please see OP, the report button is still clickable

Comment: Can you post the HTML for post-button?