# JavaScript or jQuery to bold last row of a table and remove hyperlink. Table with ID "My_Table_1"

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

Am having a dynamically generated html table and am trying to bold the last row of a table and also to remove hyperlinks from it. I want to achieve this by identifying ID *My_Table_1*.

I searched for solutions on the internet and on Stack Overflow but couldn't get any closer to what am looking for. Hence posting it with more details and specifics.

Below is the HTML:

```
<table class="a-IRR-table" id="My_Table_1">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th class="a-IRR-header">
            <a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="1971251039963326345" role="presentation">Manager</a>
            <div class="t-fht-cell"></div>
         </th>
         <th class="a-IRR-header">
            <a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="1971251173536326346" role="presentation">Col 1</a>
            <div class="t-fht-cell"></div>
         </th>
         <th class="a-IRR-header">
            <a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="1971251234003326347" role="presentation">Col 2</a>
            <div class="t-fht-cell"></div>
         </th>
         <th class="a-IRR-header">
            <a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="1971251312338326348" role="presentation">Col 3</a>
            <div class="t-fht-cell"></div>
         </th>
         <th class="a-IRR-header">
            <a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="2752728589955552718" role="presentation">Col 4</a>
            <div class="t-fht-cell"></div>
         </th>
         <th class="a-IRR-header">
            <a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="2752728614749552719" role="presentation">Col 5</a>
            <div class="t-fht-cell"></div>
         </th>
         <th class="a-IRR-header">
            <a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="1971251464506326349" role="presentation">Grand Total</a>
            <div class="t-fht-cell"></div>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class=" u-tL" headers="C1971251039963326345" aria-labelledby="C1971251039963326345"><a href="#">Manager 1</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251173536326346" aria-labelledby="C1971251173536326346"><a href="#">1</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251234003326347" aria-labelledby="C1971251234003326347"><a href="#">1</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251312338326348" aria-labelledby="C1971251312338326348"><a href="#">0</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C2752728589955552718" aria-labelledby="C2752728589955552718"><a href="#">1</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C2752728614749552719" aria-labelledby="C2752728614749552719"><a href="#">0</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251464506326349" aria-labelledby="C1971251464506326349">3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class=" u-tL" headers="C1971251039963326345" aria-labelledby="C1971251039963326345"><a href="#">Manager 2</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251173536326346" aria-labelledby="C1971251173536326346"><a href="#">161</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251234003326347" aria-labelledby="C1971251234003326347"><a href="#">3</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251312338326348" aria-labelledby="C1971251312338326348"><a href="#">108</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C2752728589955552718" aria-labelledby="C2752728589955552718"><a href="#">82</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C2752728614749552719" aria-labelledby="C2752728614749552719"><a href="#">1292</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251464506326349" aria-labelledby="C1971251464506326349">1646</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class=" u-tL" headers="C1971251039963326345" aria-labelledby="C1971251039963326345"><a href="#">Grand Total</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251173536326346" aria-labelledby="C1971251173536326346"><a href="#">162</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251234003326347" aria-labelledby="C1971251234003326347"><a href="#">4</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251312338326348" aria-labelledby="C1971251312338326348"><a href="#">108</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C2752728589955552718" aria-labelledby="C2752728589955552718"><a href="#">83</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C2752728614749552719" aria-labelledby="C2752728614749552719"><a href="#">1292</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251464506326349" aria-labelledby="C1971251464506326349">1649</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried the below JavaScript just to try to make last row bold, but it's not working:

```
#My_Table_1:tr:last-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove colon (`:`) before the `tr` in the selector. To remove the underline you have to target the `a` inside the `last-child` and set `text-decoration` and `pointer-events` property to `none`.

Try the following:

```css
#My_Table_1 tr:last-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
#My_Table_1 tr:last-child a{
  text-decoration: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="a-IRR-table" id="My_Table_1">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th class="a-IRR-header">
            <a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="1971251039963326345" role="presentation">Manager</a>
            <div class="t-fht-cell"></div>
         </th>
         <th class="a-IRR-header">
            <a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="1971251173536326346" role="presentation">Col 1</a>
            <div class="t-fht-cell"></div>
         </th>
         <th class="a-IRR-header">
            <a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="1971251234003326347" role="presentation">Col 2</a>
            <div class="t-fht-cell"></div>
         </th>
         <th class="a-IRR-header">
            <a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="1971251312338326348" role="presentation">Col 3</a>
            <div class="t-fht-cell"></div>
         </th>
         <th class="a-IRR-header">
            <a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="2752728589955552718" role="presentation">Col 4</a>
            <div class="t-fht-cell"></div>
         </th>
         <th class="a-IRR-header">
            <a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="2752728614749552719" role="presentation">Col 5</a>
            <div class="t-fht-cell"></div>
         </th>
         <th class="a-IRR-header">
            <a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="1971251464506326349" role="presentation">Grand Total</a>
            <div class="t-fht-cell"></div>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class=" u-tL" headers="C1971251039963326345" aria-labelledby="C1971251039963326345"><a href="#">Manager 1</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251173536326346" aria-labelledby="C1971251173536326346"><a href="#">1</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251234003326347" aria-labelledby="C1971251234003326347"><a href="#">1</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251312338326348" aria-labelledby="C1971251312338326348"><a href="#">0</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C2752728589955552718" aria-labelledby="C2752728589955552718"><a href="#">1</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C2752728614749552719" aria-labelledby="C2752728614749552719"><a href="#">0</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251464506326349" aria-labelledby="C1971251464506326349">3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class=" u-tL" headers="C1971251039963326345" aria-labelledby="C1971251039963326345"><a href="#">Manager 2</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251173536326346" aria-labelledby="C1971251173536326346"><a href="#">161</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251234003326347" aria-labelledby="C1971251234003326347"><a href="#">3</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251312338326348" aria-labelledby="C1971251312338326348"><a href="#">108</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C2752728589955552718" aria-labelledby="C2752728589955552718"><a href="#">82</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C2752728614749552719" aria-labelledby="C2752728614749552719"><a href="#">1292</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251464506326349" aria-labelledby="C1971251464506326349">1646</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class=" u-tL" headers="C1971251039963326345" aria-labelledby="C1971251039963326345"><a href="#">Grand Total</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251173536326346" aria-labelledby="C1971251173536326346"><a href="#">162</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251234003326347" aria-labelledby="C1971251234003326347"><a href="#">4</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251312338326348" aria-labelledby="C1971251312338326348"><a href="#">108</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C2752728589955552718" aria-labelledby="C2752728589955552718"><a href="#">83</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C2752728614749552719" aria-labelledby="C2752728614749552719"><a href="#">1292</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251464506326349" aria-labelledby="C1971251464506326349">1649</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response and help. I highly appreciate your help and time.

Comment: I tried below code `#My_Table_1 tr:last-child a{
  text-decoration: none;
}` and its not working. I was able to make it bold but unable to remove hyperlink

Comment: @Richa, is it working as you expect in the answer here? if yes, I guess css may be overridden in your actual environment.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I also clicked on "Run code snippet" on stack overflow but still I can see and click on last row. It shows as hyperlink. Please correct me if am doing something wrong here. Sorry

Comment: @Richa, which browser you are using?

Comment: Hi @Mamun, I think I fixed the issue by using method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376444/how-do-i-disable-a-href-link-in-javascript). I tried below code `#My_Table_1 tr:last-child a{ pointer-events: none !important; }` and its working fine.

Comment: @Richa, that's great. I thought you just wanted to remove the underline. To disable the click event you have to use `pointer-events`....I will update the answer....thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your css selector wasn't right (the `:` is redundant).

`#My_Table_1 tr` Selects all `<tr>` elements inside `#My_Table_1`

You can read in [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to learn how to select elements in the right way.

```css
#My_Table_1 tr:last-child { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<table class="a-IRR-table" id="My_Table_1">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th class="a-IRR-header">
            <a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="1971251039963326345" role="presentation">Manager</a>
            <div class="t-fht-cell"></div>
         </th>
         <th class="a-IRR-header">
            <a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="1971251173536326346" role="presentation">Col 1</a>
            <div class="t-fht-cell"></div>
         </th>
         <th class="a-IRR-header">
            <a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="1971251234003326347" role="presentation">Col 2</a>
            <div class="t-fht-cell"></div>
         </th>
         <th class="a-IRR-header">
            <a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="1971251312338326348" role="presentation">Col 3</a>
            <div class="t-fht-cell"></div>
         </th>
         <th class="a-IRR-header">
            <a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="2752728589955552718" role="presentation">Col 4</a>
            <div class="t-fht-cell"></div>
         </th>
         <th class="a-IRR-header">
            <a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="2752728614749552719" role="presentation">Col 5</a>
            <div class="t-fht-cell"></div>
         </th>
         <th class="a-IRR-header">
            <a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="1971251464506326349" role="presentation">Grand Total</a>
            <div class="t-fht-cell"></div>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class=" u-tL" headers="C1971251039963326345" aria-labelledby="C1971251039963326345"><a href="#">Manager 1</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251173536326346" aria-labelledby="C1971251173536326346"><a href="#">1</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251234003326347" aria-labelledby="C1971251234003326347"><a href="#">1</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251312338326348" aria-labelledby="C1971251312338326348"><a href="#">0</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C2752728589955552718" aria-labelledby="C2752728589955552718"><a href="#">1</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C2752728614749552719" aria-labelledby="C2752728614749552719"><a href="#">0</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251464506326349" aria-labelledby="C1971251464506326349">3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class=" u-tL" headers="C1971251039963326345" aria-labelledby="C1971251039963326345"><a href="#">Manager 2</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251173536326346" aria-labelledby="C1971251173536326346"><a href="#">161</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251234003326347" aria-labelledby="C1971251234003326347"><a href="#">3</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251312338326348" aria-labelledby="C1971251312338326348"><a href="#">108</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C2752728589955552718" aria-labelledby="C2752728589955552718"><a href="#">82</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C2752728614749552719" aria-labelledby="C2752728614749552719"><a href="#">1292</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251464506326349" aria-labelledby="C1971251464506326349">1646</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class=" u-tL" headers="C1971251039963326345" aria-labelledby="C1971251039963326345"><a href="#">Grand Total</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251173536326346" aria-labelledby="C1971251173536326346"><a href="#">162</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251234003326347" aria-labelledby="C1971251234003326347"><a href="#">4</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251312338326348" aria-labelledby="C1971251312338326348"><a href="#">108</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C2752728589955552718" aria-labelledby="C2752728589955552718"><a href="#">83</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C2752728614749552719" aria-labelledby="C2752728614749552719"><a href="#">1292</a></td>
         <td class=" u-tC" headers="C1971251464506326349" aria-labelledby="C1971251464506326349">1649</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response. I really appreciate your help and time.