# How to change the bootstrap class of a link after another one is clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-4

I want the bootstrap class of the link to be changed when a link is clicked .

```
<a href="link1"> link to be clicked </a>
<a href="link2" id="x" name = "x" class="btn btn-info btn-sm disabled">link to be changed</a>
```

Comment: Links do not have a `disabled` attribute, that is a thing for form controls. Search terms like “javascript disable link” would have easily led you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376444/how-do-i-disable-a-href-link-in-javascript

Comment: @04FS i'm using bootstrap

Comment: And what does that have to do with anything, regarding this particular question?

Comment: @04FS using bootstrap we can add a class with disabled attribute,

Comment: @04FS well i can reform the question like that : how to change the class of a link after another one is clicked

Comment: Well you know how to react to the click happening already, so this would then boil down to, _“how do I add/remove/change the class(es) of an element with JavaScript”_, and that, again, should be rather easy to research.

Comment: @04FS thanks , i will change the question

Comment: _“using bootstrap we can add a class with disabled attribute”_ - please link to the documentation of what exactly you are referring to here.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you don't want the link to be clicked, you could always just hide it using javascript.

```
<a href="#" onClick='document.getElementById("2").style.display = "none"'>link to be clicked </a>
<a href="#" id="2" name = "2">link to be disabled</a>
```

EDIT: Just noticed you updated your question, you can try this it adds the disabled class to the link.

```
<a href="#" onClick='document.getElementById("2").classList.add("disabled")'>link to be clicked </a>
<a href="#" id="2" name = "2">link to be disabled</a>
```

You can read more about the disabled class on the bootstrap documentation here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#disabled-state

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code as below, it will help you to achieve your requirement easily.

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
 <a href='#' OnClick = "document.getElementById('2').removeAttribute('Class');document.getElementById('2').setAttribute('Class','btn btn-info btn-sm disabled');" > link 
   to be clicked </a>
   <a href="link2" Class='btn btn-info btn-sm' id="2" name = "2"> link to be disabled </a>
</body>
</html>
```